# Camunda :inovoking http service inside embedded html form

Tags: json, camunda, camunda-modeler

My service response  is json array and  i want  to parse it and  make as many embedded html forms as many json elemnts i  have  in my json array.
and  here  are  several  subjects  i am intersted in:
is  it  possible to invoke and  parse rest  service  inside camunda embedded form  ,**How  can  i do  it?**